HandsonTable with useState on React
I have a table made with handsontable where I have a list of bools to save the state of each row and column and by clicking a rowHeader or columnHeader, the state is modified and depending on the state, whether it is true or false, the column/row is painted red or green. I do it using useState but when I update a variable, as useState renders the page again, if I am on row 100, it shows me the initial view again where only the first 20 rows are seen. How do I keep my vision from moving?
This is the code where I update the state and paint the cells the color they need
afterOnCellMouseDown: function(event, coords) {
                    if (coords.row === -1 && coords.col === -1) {
                        setColumnStates(Array(Object.keys(datasetData[1]).length).fill(true));
                        setRowStates(Array(Object.keys(datasetData).length).fill(false));
                    } else if (coords.row === -1) {
                        let newColumnStates = {...columnStates};
                        newColumnStates[coords.col] = !newColumnStates[coords.col];
                        setColumnStates(newColumnStates);
                    } else if (coords.col === -1) {
                        let newRowStates = {...rowStates};
                        newRowStates[coords.row] = !newRowStates[coords.row];
                        setRowStates(newRowStates);
                    }

                    hotInstance.current.render();
                },
                cells: function(row, col, prop) {
                    const cellProperties = {};
                    if (!columnStates[col]) {
                        cellProperties.renderer = function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                            td.style.backgroundColor = '#e6adad';
                        };
                    } else if (rowStates[row]) {
                        cellProperties.renderer = function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                            td.style.backgroundColor = '#a1d690';
                        };
                    } else {
                        cellProperties.renderer = function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                            td.style.backgroundColor = '';
                        };
                    }
                    return cellProperties;
                },

I have tried using scrollTop to maintain the view but it does not work well for me
On the next link you can see how my table works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuRD7TLS7ZY
